# api pull custom field value based on id not label

Tags: contacts, custom-fields, api, apiv4

Using API 4 (php), how do I retreive a custom field value for a specific contact, using the custom field id instead of the custom field name.

This works (for contact with id=1234), but requires the use of the custom field name (Extra_Info.My_Custom_Field_Name), but I want to use the custom field id of say 37:

```
$result = civicrm_api4('Contact', 'get', [ 
  'checkPermissions' => FALSE, 
  'select' => [ 'Extra_Info.My_Custom_Field_Name', ], 
  'where' => [ ['id', '=', '1234'], ], 
  'limit' => 1,
]);
```

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do that?  One of the benefits of APIv4 vs APIv3 is that you don't need to mess around with those field numbers.

Comment: @aidan Mostly because that is how I was trying to do it originally and could not figure out how to do it that way...  so now I just want to know how!

Comment: Ah!  I don't that you can do that directly.  You could use `CustomField::get()->addSelect('name', 'custom_group_id:name')->addWhere('id', '=', 37)` to get the field and group names to plug into your existing query.